# Select an attribute from an element that has a valid date as a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Javascript/jQuery selector question (see codepen link below). The structure (HTML in the fiddle) is actually Excel XML created by jQuery Datatables when you export to Excel, but the codepen works all the same.

Basically, I could go deeper if needed on what the end goal is, but at the moment I’m trying to get the column letter (r attribute from row 1, aka the Excel header row) for each column that has a date as a header. So `validDateColumns` should be `[D,E,F,G,H]`.

I set up the codepen so it is already logging out the right things - I just could use some help with the right selector statement for `validDateColumns`. TIA!

https://codepen.io/murphydan/pen/wpVYPm?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code just apply on *first row* and remove *last character* ("1") of value of `r` attribute. I used same Technic that *@RoryMcCrossan* used in his answer and just corrected it by some modifications to make the result that you want.

```js
var validDateCols = $('row[r="1"] > c').filter(function() {
  return moment($(this).text().trim(), "MM/DD/YY", true).isValid()
}).map(function() {
   return $(this).attr('r').slice(0, -1);
}).get();

console.log(validDateCols);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
<sheetData xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <row r="1" xmlns="">
    <c r="A1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Cell</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="B1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>LIDS WIP</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="C1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Late</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="D1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>01/25/18</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="E1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>01/26/18</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="F1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>01/29/18</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="G1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>01/30/18</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="H1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>01/31/18</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="I1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>DB</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="J1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>OS</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="K1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Days of Work</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="L1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Work in Period</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="M1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Avg Pieces per Day</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="N1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Cell Capacity</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="O1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>SAP Window Open To</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="P1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Incoming Work</t>
      </is>
    </c>
  </row>
  <row r="2" xmlns="">
    <c r="A2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Acrylic Trophy Hub</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="B2" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="C2" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="D2" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="E2" s="20" t="n">
      <v>12</v>
    </c>
    <c r="F2" t="n">
      <v>2</v>
    </c>
    <c r="G2" s="20" t="n">
      <v>120</v>
    </c>
    <c r="H2" s="20" t="n">
      <v>312</v>
    </c>
    <c r="I2" t="n">
      <v>26</v>
    </c>
    <c r="J2" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="K2" t="n">
      <v>0.00</v>
    </c>
    <c r="L2" t="n">
      <v>472</v>
    </c>
    <c r="M2" t="n">
      <v>0.00</v>
    </c>
    <c r="N2" t="n">
      <v>6</v>
    </c>
    <c r="O2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>02/02/18</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="P2" t="n">
      <v>41</v>
    </c>
  </row>
  <row r="3" xmlns="">
    <c r="A3" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>ADC4</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="B3" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="C3" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="D3" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="E3" s="20" t="n">
      <v>25</v>
    </c>
    <c r="F3" s="20" t="n">
      <v>18</v>
    </c>
    <c r="G3" t="n">
      <v>3</v>
    </c>
    <c r="H3" s="20" t="n">
      <v>18</v>
    </c>
    <c r="I3" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="J3" t="n">
      <v>24</v>
    </c>
    <c r="K3" t="n">
      <v>0.34</v>
    </c>
    <c r="L3" t="n">
      <v>88</v>
    </c>
    <c r="M3" t="n">
      <v>257.88</v>
    </c>
    <c r="N3" t="n">
      <v>12</v>
    </c>
    <c r="O3" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>01/31/18</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="P3" t="n">
      <v>225</v>
    </c>
  </row>
</sheetData>
```

Comment: Nice! This even works when the columns extend past Z (e.g. AA1, AB1, AC1, etc).

Comment: @dmurphy, Yes it always remove last character regardless of the length of the col name.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can first `filter()` the `c` nodes to retrieve only those which contain a valid date. Then you can use `map()` to create an array of the `r` properties from those nodes. Something like this:

```js
var validDateColumns = $('c').filter(function() {
  return moment($(this).text().trim(), "MM/DD/YY", true).isValid()
}).map(function() {
   return $(this).attr('r');
}).get();

console.log(validDateColumns);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
<sheetData xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <row r="1" xmlns="">
    <c r="A1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Cell</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="B1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>LIDS WIP</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="C1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Late</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="D1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>01/25/18</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="E1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>01/26/18</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="F1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>01/29/18</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="G1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>01/30/18</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="H1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>01/31/18</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="I1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>DB</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="J1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>OS</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="K1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Days of Work</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="L1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Work in Period</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="M1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Avg Pieces per Day</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="N1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Cell Capacity</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="O1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>SAP Window Open To</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="P1" s="2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Incoming Work</t>
      </is>
    </c>
  </row>
  <row r="2" xmlns="">
    <c r="A2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>Acrylic Trophy Hub</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="B2" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="C2" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="D2" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="E2" s="20" t="n">
      <v>12</v>
    </c>
    <c r="F2" t="n">
      <v>2</v>
    </c>
    <c r="G2" s="20" t="n">
      <v>120</v>
    </c>
    <c r="H2" s="20" t="n">
      <v>312</v>
    </c>
    <c r="I2" t="n">
      <v>26</v>
    </c>
    <c r="J2" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="K2" t="n">
      <v>0.00</v>
    </c>
    <c r="L2" t="n">
      <v>472</v>
    </c>
    <c r="M2" t="n">
      <v>0.00</v>
    </c>
    <c r="N2" t="n">
      <v>6</v>
    </c>
    <c r="O2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>02/02/18</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="P2" t="n">
      <v>41</v>
    </c>
  </row>
  <row r="3" xmlns="">
    <c r="A3" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>ADC4</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="B3" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="C3" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="D3" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="E3" s="20" t="n">
      <v>25</v>
    </c>
    <c r="F3" s="20" t="n">
      <v>18</v>
    </c>
    <c r="G3" t="n">
      <v>3</v>
    </c>
    <c r="H3" s="20" t="n">
      <v>18</v>
    </c>
    <c r="I3" t="n">
      <v>0</v>
    </c>
    <c r="J3" t="n">
      <v>24</v>
    </c>
    <c r="K3" t="n">
      <v>0.34</v>
    </c>
    <c r="L3" t="n">
      <v>88</v>
    </c>
    <c r="M3" t="n">
      <v>257.88</v>
    </c>
    <c r="N3" t="n">
      <v>12</v>
    </c>
    <c r="O3" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>01/31/18</t>
      </is>
    </c>
    <c r="P3" t="n">
      <v>225</v>
    </c>
  </row>
</sheetData>
```

Comment: Ok, so that is super close. It looks like it is picking up the date that is in row 2 and 3 in column O though. I shouldn't get O2 and O3 in the validDateColumns array and I only need the letter in the result set. So `["D","E","F","G","H"]` instead of `["D1", "E1", "F1", "G1", "H1", "O2", "O3"]`. Does that make sense?